# Open source android widget creator

Tags: android, widget

I'm looking for an alternative to something like [KWGT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kustom.widget&hl=en_US) that is open source, couldn't find anything on fdroid, fossdroid or on alternative.to

It doesn't have to be as easy to create widgets, I'm okay with doing a lot of the work myself, I really just need/want a foss alternative.